# Troubleshooting mysql database connections in django python when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, django, database, multiprocessing, mariadb

```
OS: CentOS 8 4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64
Python: 3.8
Django: 3.1.7
Apache: 2.4.37-30
Mariadb: 3:10.3.27-3
```

I have a website built in django and served via Apache via wsgi. The application makes use of multiprocessing.

I wrote a decorator with which I decorate all of my views.

Decorator:

```
def counterDecorator(view_func, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(request, **kwargs):
        if not request.session.session_key:
            request.session.save()
            
        device_type = 'Unknown'
        
        if request.user_agent.is_mobile:
            device_type = 'Mobile'
        elif request.user_agent.is_tablet:
            device_type = 'Tablet'
        elif request.user_agent.is_pc:
            device_type = 'Desktop'
        elif request.user_agent.is_bot:
            device_type = 'Bot'
            
        keywords = {'s_key': request.session.session_key,
                    'ip_addr': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], 
                    'browser': request.user_agent.browser.family,
                    'browser_version': request.user_agent.browser.version_string,
                    'operating_system': request.user_agent.os.family,
                    'operating_system_version': request.user_agent.os.version_string,
                    'device': request.user_agent.device.family,
                    'device_type': device_type,
                    'view_uri': request.path
                }
        
        p = Process(target=count, kwargs=keywords)
        p.start()
        
        return view_func(request, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Now as you can see this decorator prepares the data and then starts a new process, where a count function is called

```
def count(s_key, ip_addr, browser, browser_version, operating_system, operating_system_version, device, device_type, view_uri):
    try:
        conn = create_connection()
        print(conn)
    except Exception as e:
        f = open(BASE_DIR + "/LOG.txt", "a")
        f.write(e)
        f.close()
    
    if UniqueUserModel.objects.filter(session_key=s_key).exists():
            UUM = UniqueUserModel.objects.filter(session_key=s_key).get()
            UUM.viewsmodel_set.create(user_model=UUM, view=view_uri, view_time_stamp=datetime.datetime.now())
    else:
        UUM = UniqueUserModel()
        
        UUM.session_key                 = s_key
        UUM.ip_addr                     = ip_addr
        if ip_addr != '127.0.0.1':
            UUM.country = GeoIP2().country(ip_addr).get('country_name')
        else:
            UUM.country = 'localhost'
            
        UUM.time_stamp                  = datetime.datetime.now()
        UUM.browser                     = browser
        UUM.browser_version             = browser_version
        UUM.operating_system            = operating_system
        UUM.operating_system_version    = operating_system_version
        UUM.device                      = device
        UUM.device_type                 = device_type
        
        UUM.save()
        UUM.viewsmodel_set.create(user_model = UUM, view = view_uri, view_time_stamp=datetime.datetime.now())
        
        conn.close()
```

As you can see the count function will create its own connection with the create_connection function to the database.

```
def create_connection(alias=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS):
    connections.ensure_defaults(alias)
    connections.prepare_test_settings(alias)
    db = connections.databases[alias]
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
    
    return backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
```

However from time to time I get an error:

```
connections.py", line 705, in _read_packet
         raise err.InternalError(
     pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 129 expected 1

 django.db.utils.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 129 expected 1
```

The database from my settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
           'NAME': 'db_name',
           'USER': 'user',
           'PASSWORD': 'db_pass',
           'HOST': 'address',
           'PORT': '3306',
           #'CONN_MAX_AGE': 100,
       }
   }
```

Example of a view function:

```
@require_http_methods(["GET"])
@counterDecorator
def home(request):
    about_us = AboutUsModel.objects.all().first()
    blog_header = BlogHeader.objects.all().first()
    latest_blogs = BlogModel.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:3]

    context = {
        'about_us': about_us,
        'blog_header': blog_header,
        'latest_blogs': latest_blogs,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'landing.html', context)
```

I would would like to identify and solve the problem.
Initially I though that the issue might be with the connection, but as you can see each instance of the count function will create its own connection to the database and close it. I understand that more try except statements should be put around the connection attempts but I am still working on it. At this time I really cannot figure what the issue is or how to fix it, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you all for your time and effort.

Comment: What's the advantage of using multiprocessing here? That's why you use a web framework so you don't have to deal with all the underlying logic. The app server like [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) for example, will use [sync workers](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#sync-workers) with multiprocessing  by default. Why do you also open a new connection to the database if you use an ORM anyway?

Comment: "What's the advantage of using multiprocessing here? " So that the code is nonblocking. And the site loads faster. At least that is my assumption. As per documentation from the previous posts, the connection cannot be shared to the database and in each fork you need to create a new one and close it, at least the way I have read it.

Comment: `1.` Your application server will probably use multiprocessing more efficiently than your approach here (now you just spawn a separate process for each request so it's relatively easy to overload your server). `2.` Django ORM will mange the connections for you so no need to create an extra connection that it's not used anyway (despite the fact it's not closed in the `if` branch as well)

Comment: @HTF Thank you for the insight. Even though this is not a direct answer to the question I very much appreciate your input and the time you took to help me out. It does however send me in a different direction making the question no longer of importance in my case. As I ll most likely just add the  function call count inside of view via a decorate without the multiprocess. Again thank you  for your time and input.